# Open poup infront of respective divs for mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website design in which it has 90% wide rounded boxes stacked vertically.
each rounded box height varies from 480px to 800px due to its dynamic content..it shows a popup when clicked...popup window height similarly varies from 480px to 800px..and the popup should appear right infront of the corresponding rounded box. I did this by giving seperate ids for each popup and positioning it absolute. 
The issue is that the mobile site has around 38 rounded box with popups...I had to create 38 ids and apply css positioning for each popup.. Is there a better way to achieve this?

check the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/4eLfq4u7/

```
<div class="rounded_box" id="one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ducimus tempora deserunt repellat architecto adipisci. Nulla est voluptatem, expedita possimus veniam tempora voluptate inventore eius
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your html to make something like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="roundedBox"></div>
  <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

your js can then work like that:

```
$(".wrapper").click(".roundedBox", function () {
     $(".popup", this).toggle();
});
```

according to your css since positioning absolute is also relative - to it's parent, you don't need to position every popup via id.

see working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4eLfq4u7/1/